# King of Shimron vs king of Shimron-meron

Tags: joshua

In Joshua 11:1 (NASB)

> Then it came about, when Jabin king of Hazor heard about it, that he sent word to Jobab king of Madon, to the **king of Shimron**, to the king of Achshaph,

and in Joshua 12:20 (NASB)

> the **king of Shimron-meron**, one; the king of Achshaph, one;

Is the king of Shimron referenced in Joshua 11 the same as king of Shimron-meron from Joshua 12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joshua won a great victory in chapter 10 and the sun stood still. Other kings decided to join forces to fight against Joshua in Chapter 11 including the king of Shimron:

> 1 When Jabin king of Hazor heard of this, he sent word to Jobab king of Madon, to the kings of **Shimron** and **Akshaph**,

They were also defeated as listed in Joshua 12:

> 20
> the king of **Shimron Meron** one the king of **Akshaph** one

Yes, king of Shimron was the same one as king of Shimron Meron. Joshua even kept the order of the two names: Shimron, then Akahaph.
Cambridge Bible for Schools and Colleges mentions that Shimron Meron is the full name.

Before Joshua retired, he allotted the territory of Shimron to Zebulun in Joshua 19:

> 10 The third lot came up for Zebulun according to its clans: ...
>
> 15 Included were Kattath, Nahalal, **Shimron**, Idalah and Bethlehem. There were twelve towns and their villages.

Everything is quite consistent if we treat the two names pointing to the same place.